# Batch spliting a text file by string and name it

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, text

I have this batch file to meagre a text file:

```
@echo off
del merged.txt>nul
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    type %%I >> merged.txt
    echo. >> merged.txt
    echo ----SPLIT---- %%~nxI% >> merged.txt
)
```

Once it is combined I need a way to split it again at a later date. How could I split it every time a line says `----SPLIT----` and then name the file after what it says on the same line after `----SPLIT----`. Thanks in advance.

In response:

This is what the split text file looks like when combined:

```
func porblem()
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & 'rmdir /s /q Func', "", @SW_HIDE)
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & 'mkdir Func', "", @SW_HIDE)
    MsgBox(0, "Fixed","That should fix the problem. If it does not let me know on the website")
    exit
endfunc 
----SPLIT---- Func0.au3 
#include <Constants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <GDIPlus.au3>
$hGUI1 = GUICreate('GUI',480,150)
Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 1)
$Pic1 = GUICtrlCreatePic("Images\LOGO.bmp", 360, 0, 100, 70)
$Pic1 = GUICtrlCreatePic("Images\Full-Optimise.bmp", 20, 10, 280, 60)
GUICtrlCreateButton("Normal", 190,80,100,40)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "start")
GUICtrlCreateButton("Advanced", 360,80,100,40)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "gui2")
GUICtrlCreateButton("Exit", 20,80,100,40)
GUICtrlSetOnEvent(-1, "exitx")
GUISetState()
While 1
   Sleep(100)
WEnd
func start()
    Run("Func4.exe")
    exit
endfunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set lastLine=0
< merged.txt (
   for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"----SPLIT----" merged.txt') do (
      set /A numLines=%%a-lastLine-1, lastLine=%%a
      (for /L %%i in (1,1,!numLines!) do (
         set "line="
         set /P line=
         echo(!line!
      )) > %%b
      set /P line=
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Answer to the comment*

I did a test and my solution seems to works correctly.

merged.txt:

```
These lines
are the contents
of FirstFile.txt
----SPLIT---- FirstFile.txt
Two Two Two Two Two Two Two
Number 2, Number 2
----SPLIT---- SecondFile.txt
The contents
of Third file
is here!
----SPLIT---- ThirdFile.txt
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat

C:\> type FirstFile.txt
These lines
are the contents
of FirstFile.txt

C:\> type SecondFile.txt
Two Two Two Two Two Two Two
Number 2, Number 2

C:\> type ThirdFile.txt
The contents
of Third file
is here!
```

Please, post your data and your results, so I can fix the problem...

Comment: The naming system seems to work but it spits between 0-50 lines above the ----SPLIT----.Thanks if you can help with this.

Comment: Just thought I could mention the text file has `:;@'~#-_=+]{}[?><.,/"'$%^&()` In it this my be the source of the problem.

Comment: My method does not have the problem of the special Batch characters management, because it read the data via `set /P`. _Please, post your data and your results, so I can fix the problem_... Do this via an edit in your question; do NOT post data here as comments, but post a comment here as advice when you did that.

Comment: The data you posted does _NOT_ have the name of the second file! After I added this line at end: `----SPLIT---- Func1.au3` my program correctly created the two files...

Comment: This is just a section the full file is 50,000 lines plus long.

Comment: I have just tested a extract and it seems to be the merge script that I faulty. Do you know how I can sort this.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (merged.xtx) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /b /L /C:"----SPLIT----" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"%destdir%\temp.txt" ECHO(%%a
  ) ELSE (
  SET "orgname=%%a"
  SET "orgname=!orgname:* =!"
  REN "%destdir%\temp.txt" "!orgname!"
 )
)
```

(fixed a little to suit my system

- `merged` file renamed so it's not included with the other `.txt` files
- `%destdir%` added so that re-created files are in a distinct directory

)

[response to comment]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
u:
CD \sourcedir

del merged.xtx>nul
for %%I in (*.txt) do (
    type %%I >> merged.xtx
    echo.>> merged.xtx
    >>merged.xtx echo ----SPLIT---- %%~nxI
)

SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (merged.xtx) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /b /L /C:"----SPLIT----" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"%destdir%\temp.txt" ECHO(%%a
  ) ELSE (
  SET "orgname=%%a"
  SET "orgname=!orgname:* =!"
  REN "%destdir%\temp.txt" "!orgname!"
 )
)

CD \
c:

GOTO :EOF
```

This is the full test batch I used.

Most of the parts I omitted have to do with swapping directories - `u:\sourcedir` containing my test `.txt` files, `u:\destdir` my result files, and I do the development on my `c:` drive.

I did change your original a little. I switched the output syntax around to drop superfluous spaces and removed a stray `%`. I also dropped the space after the `echo.`

This worked for me and `fc /w` reported identical files in the source and destination (the `/w` tells `fc` to ignore whitespace differences). The files were not identical because of `for /f`'s games with empty lines and possible insertion/dropping of spaces along the way.

Works for me! - would need to examine your data more closely to come to any conclusion about problems. Perhaps aligning your generate-merged-file code with my version may be a cure.

Comment: The naming system seems to work but it spits between 0-50 lines above the `----SPLIT----`.Thanks if you can help with this.